# Django search - populate template with search results

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm completely newbie in Django-phython.
I'm trying to populate the results of a search inside an html form input tag. with the register that the search returns.

I have a view that renders an html code, passing a dictionary. And I would like to display that dictionary, containing the search results, inside the html form fields that corresponds to that dictionary.

The question is if it's possible to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You will get all the information at [django template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/)

Specifically, if you want to iterate through the dictionary in your template, you need the [for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-for) loop.

From the documentation:

> This can also be useful if you need to access the items in a
>   dictionary. For example, if your context contained a dictionary data,
>   the following would display the keys and values of the dictionary:

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use [ajax](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/ajax.html) and a [typehead pulgin](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) for that.